# Google OAuth consent screen for external application behind login page

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I'm trying to verify my app for external use. I'm getting an email from Google which makes absolutely no sense.

*It appears that the submitted Homepage URL: http://myappname.azurewebsites.net/manage is a Log-in and/or Sign-in page, which restricts public access to your app's information and intent.*

In order to use the Google features of my application, a user must first login to my app using their application credentials. Once they are logged in, they can setup the Google feature by clicking on a button that walks them through the Google OAuth process. The end result is that we obtain a token to use on their behalf. We tell them exactly what permissions we are asking for and even show them how to revoke access whenever they want to. We also specify in our Privacy Policy what permissions we are requesting and how their data will be used.

Seeing as we are not using Google for sign-in, then how are we supposed to implement this feature if the so-called home page is behind a login screen and the app is for external users???

Comment: Your homepage needs to be your registered domain.

Comment: What does this mean? The domain is an Azure Websites domain that has been authorized.

Comment: You do not own the Azure domain `azurewebsites.net`. You must use a domain that you own.

Comment: @JohnHanley I went ahead and added my actual domain with SSL. Still waiting to hear back from Google to see if that worked. The instructions and email response from Google are extremely misleading. Thanks!

Comment: I made the change. Google is asking me to make my privacy policy publicly accessible, which it already is. Not sure why they are still flagging that. They are also flagging the homepage with this comment. "Comply with homepage requirements
Ensure your homepage is publicly accessible and meets all requirements." The homepage is publicly accessible, but you have to login to access it. I've built other Google integrations. They all require a login of some sort. So frustrating! Waiting to hear back.

Comment: Perhaps you are misunderstanding Google's requirements. You must have a public website located on a domain you own that anyone can access. If you have already done that provide the URL and we can verify that it is public.

Comment: That's been done. Seems like I'm good, but we'll see what happens next. For whatever reason, the email from Google keeps pointing to the fact that when they try to access the link (homepage), it takes them to a sign-in page. This is by design. I'm not using Google for a login. Perhaps this is just a standard response they are using. From my perspective, it's confusing. As a developer, I have to deal with the same type of stuff from Facebook, though. For whatever reason, tech people have made app attestation so confusing, and therefore difficult. Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: You state `when they try to access the link (homepage), it takes them to a sign-in page. This is by design.`. Your home page, privacy page, etc. must be public without a login being required.

Comment: How is that possible??? A user must first login to my app using my apps credentials before they can start the OAuth process with Google to get the token for the Google APIs my app needs access to. The only way to make that public is to use Google for the login. That wouldn't work in so many situations. If the homepage was public, then I wouldn't know which user of mine to save the access token for.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just went and looked at another Google OAuth consent I did for some other apps and services I've built. It appears that the homepage just needs to be the marketing website for the app or service. I'm not sure why they can't just say that in the instructions or in the email response. I made the change. Let's see what happens. By the way, I figured it out by reading comments from other developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the marketing website for my entire platform/solution as the homepage. On the main page, I list the Google feature (how it's used) and include a screen shot. Just below that I added these words. "*(App's) use and transfer to any other app of information received from Google APIs will adhere to Google API Services User Data Policy, including the Limited Use requirements.*" Finally, I made sure that the privacy policy (with Google requirements regarding permissions requested and how data is used) along with the terms and conditions were linked on the page.

Answer (score 2):

> Application homepage URL. The location of a homepage describing your app. This location must hosted on an authorized domain.

This is not the login page.

Comment: Thanks! The domain is authorized. I wonder why they won't approve the app then???

Comment: I went ahead and added the full domain http://myappname.azurewebsites.net/manage to the Google Search Console and used the site verification tag method to authorize the domain. I created a folder called manage and placed the Google site tag there. Waiting to hear back to see if this worked.

Comment: I will be surprised if that works you don't own azurewebsites.net.

Comment: I went ahead and added my actual domain with SSL. Still waiting to hear back from Google to see if that worked. The instructions and email response from Google are extremely misleading.

Comment: I made the change. Google is asking me to make my privacy policy publicly accessible, which it already is. Not sure why they are still flagging that. They are also flagging the homepage with this comment. "Comply with homepage requirements
Ensure your homepage is publicly accessible and meets all requirements." The homepage is publicly accessible, but you have to login to access it. I've built other Google integrations. They all require a login of some sort. So frustrating! Waiting to hear back.

Comment: is it your own domain that you registered

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm still having problems, though. Google is now bringing up something completely new. I just responded. We'll see what happens next. This is nothing new. For whatever reason, app attestation is so confusing and therefore difficult. Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: I just went and looked at another Google OAuth consent I did for some other apps and services I've built. It appears that the homepage just needs to be the marketing website for the app or service. I'm not sure why they can't just say that in the instructions or in the email response. I made the change. Let's see what happens. By the way, I figured it out by reading comments from other developers.